# Why is there a gap/space between the navigation and header divs?

Tags: html, css

hoping someone can explain why there is a gap between the "nav" and "header" divs?  I think its something to do with the text but can't find the right solution for the CSS.  Any help is much appreciate :)

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height:100%;
}

body {
 background-color: black;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

audio { 
 width: 300px; 
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: brown;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: grey;
}

#main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.lyrics {
 max-width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<title>
 Test
</title>
<body>
 <div id="main">
 <div class="nav">
 </div><!-- nav -->
 <div class="header">
 <h1>Web Page</h1>
 </div><!--header-->
 
 <div class="lyrics">
 <p>text1</p>

 <p>text2</p>

 <p>text3</p>

 </div> <!-- lyrics -->
 
 </div> <!-- main div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inspect with firebug -- always the best way to find gaps/spaces/padding/margins you weren't expecting.

Comment: floating over the h1 code snippet on the HTML tab from firebug you can see it highlight the space, so you can identify the h1 as the problem.

Comment: There are html5 tags for both `header` and `nav` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are talking about the black space above the "Web Page" title? In which case you just need to remove the top margin of the h1 like I did below:

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height:100%;
}

body {
 background-color: black;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

audio { 
 width: 300px; 
}

.header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 font-size: 0.9em;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 background-color: brown;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 7%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: grey;
}

#main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.lyrics {
 max-width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
 color: white;
}

h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<title>
 Test
</title>
<body>
 <div id="main">
 <div class="nav">
 </div><!-- nav -->
 <div class="header">
 <h1>Web Page</h1>
 </div><!--header-->
 
 <div class="lyrics">
 <p>text1</p>

 <p>text2</p>

 <p>text3</p>

 </div> <!-- lyrics -->
 
 </div> <!-- main div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't explain the reason behind this.

Comment: It's coming from the browser's default stylesheet for `h1`.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, but the OP asked `why there is a gap...` not `what is causing the gap...`.

Comment: Ah, but by the OP's ommitting of the fact that it is the h1 causing the problem we can infer that he was wonder what the cause was and not necessarily why.

Comment: Okay, I leave this as a comment rather than an answer; The reason is that adjoining vertical margins of two or more block-level elements collapses into a single margin whose value is largest — See: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Comment: I did want to know why there was a gap and since a user kindly gave a solution I can figure out why.

Comment: All of your input is very valuable and it is helping me and others learn :)

Comment: In this particular case there is not a gap, since the h1 is nested if cssnoob was to put a border on the div he would see that it does in fact wrap the child h1 element such that there is no gap.  It just appears there is a gap visually.

Comment: @UncleIroh If only there were a border on the div... You'd see no gap anymore visually/actually.

Answer (score 0):

remove the top margin of the h1